# Need to make on object in Javascript based on an existing object which is efficient considering its performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
{
  "name": "test name",
  "description": "test desc",
  "data_table_id": 3,
  "column_0": {
    "value": "1",
    "label": "name"
  },
  "condition_0": {
    "value": "101",
    "label": "Is equal to"
  },
  "column_1": {
    "value": "2",
    "label": "age"
  },
  "condition_1": {
    "value": "102",
    "label": "Is less than"
  }
}
```

I have the above object in JavaScript. From this object I need to create the following object. Need to find a way which is good from performance point of view. The below conditions array is based on the object starting with 'column_' in the above object.
For example: if there are column_0, column_1, column_2, the length of conditions array will be 3. These columns will be coming dynamically, can be from 0-n, n = any integer >= 0. **(i.e. column_0 - column_n)**

The same condition applies for condition_0, condition_1. Also, condition_0 is always associated with column_0, condition_1 is always associated with column_1 ans so on.

```
{
    "name": "test name",
    "description": "test desc",
    "data_table_id": 3,
    "conditions" : [
      {
          "column_id": 1, // column_0.value
          "column_name": "name", // column_0.label
          "condition_id": 101 // condition_0.value
      },
      {
          "column_id": 2, // column_1.value
          "column_name": "age", // column_1.label
          "condition_id": 102 // condition_1.value
      }
  ],
}
```

Comment: Is `data_table_id` the number of columns and conditions?

Comment: @JackBashford no it is just a key, has nothing to do with the number of columns and conditions

Comment: Define "efficient" -- you have few options other than iterating, breaking apart the keys to find array positions, etc.

Comment: If it needs to be more efficient that simple iteration (ie, the regex parsing of the key names is too much), then I'd recommend trying to fix the data at the source. "column_0", "condition_0" etc are rather poor key names.

Comment: yes, resolved it at the root level itself. Changed the structure and key names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extract the conditions using `...rest`, reduce the `Object.entries` , construct the data structure and push it to the resulting array, finally put everything back together :

```js
const data = {
  "name": "test name",
  "description": "test desc",
  "data_table_id": 3,
  "column_0": {
    "value": "1",
    "label": "name"
  },
  "condition_0": {
    "value": "101",
    "label": "Is equal to"
  },
  "column_1": {
    "value": "2",
    "label": "age"
  },
  "condition_1": {
    "value": "102",
    "label": "Is less than"
  }
}

const {
  name,
  description,
  data_table_id,
  ...rest
} = data;

const conditions = Object.entries(rest).reduce((all, [key, obj]) => {
  if (key.startsWith('condition')) {
    const id = key.split('_')[1];

    const condition = {
      "column_id": rest[`column_${id}`].value,
      "column_name": rest[`column_${id}`].label,
      "condition_id": obj.value,
    }

    all.push(condition)
  }


  return all;
}, []);

const result = {
  name,
  description,
  data_table_id,
  conditions
}

console.log(result)
```